# How to space items evenly in a HorizontalScrollView if content is smaller than the container

Tags: android

I am trying to make a `HorizontalScrollView` to behave as a `LinearLayout` in terms of stretching it's children **if** the content of the `HorizontalScrollView` is not wide enough to scroll.

With the layout below items are spaced with space between, which is exactly how it should look like if the screen is wide. But there is no scrolling if screen width is too small or font is too big this layout.

```xml
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/appearance_row_0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginVertical="12dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
            <include layout="@layout/appearance_fragment_theme_button"/>
            <include layout="@layout/appearance_fragment_divider"/>
            <include layout="@layout/appearance_fragment_theme_button"/>
            <include layout="@layout/appearance_fragment_divider"/>
            <include layout="@layout/appearance_fragment_theme_button"/>
            <include layout="@layout/appearance_fragment_divider"/>
            <include layout="@layout/appearance_fragment_theme_button"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

With the layout below scrolling is possible, but items are placed in the center, without any space between the items.

```xml
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/appearance_row_0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginVertical="12dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
            <include layout="@layout/appearance_fragment_theme_button"/>
            <include layout="@layout/appearance_fragment_divider"/>
            <include layout="@layout/appearance_fragment_theme_button"/>
            <include layout="@layout/appearance_fragment_divider"/>
            <include layout="@layout/appearance_fragment_theme_button"/>
            <include layout="@layout/appearance_fragment_divider"/>
            <include layout="@layout/appearance_fragment_theme_button"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

[image: items are placed in the center, but it scrolls if necessary]

It there a way to combine both behaviors, namely to put space between items if the screen is wide enough to accommodate the content and to scroll if the screen is not wide enough?

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you use `space` to have fixed space between your items? in that case, you always have the same space between your items. If the screen is wide enough, all items are shown without the need to scrolling. Otherwise, the `HorizontalScrollView` lets the user scroll. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I could achieve this using a recycler view. Since recycler view was not in the question, posting a GitHub link for the implementation rather than an answer here - https://github.com/Abhimanyu14/auto-spacing-horizontal-scroll-view. 
P.S: This works only if the children views size are the same and fixed.
Let me know if this suits your purpose.